# How can I keep memory of a transformation through sklearn.Normalizer for a later use?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization

The numbers in this example are reduced to make the thing more readable. I actually work with more and bigger data.

Currently I am using the Normalizer from sklearn.preprocessing to normalize a matrix:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

tab = csr_matrix((5, 10))
tab[2,3] = 1
tab[4,5] = 2 #The columns represent my 10 items in a 5-dimensions space

transformer = Normalizer(norm='l1')
tab = transformer.fit_transform(tab.T).T #normalize by column
```

This works as I expected (it transforms `tab` so it is normalized column-wise).

But now I have a new array `arr` (of size 5) and I want to apply to it the same transformation that occurred on the columns of tab. I can't do:

```
result = transformer.transform(arr)
```

because .transform expects a matrix and anyway don't keep memory of the previous transformation. How can I manage to keep this memory?

I need the solution to be the most efficient possible considering the total amount of data (the size of `tab`)

Comment: Normalizer works on samples, so whats the use of remembering previous transformation. Can you please explain on what you want to do. Do you want to scale your columns, then you should use StandardScaler, not Normalizer.

Comment: You are right, I was misusing Normalizer. StandardScaler seems to be exactly what I was looking for!